# Mathematical research in North Korea -- reference request

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

**Question:** Where can one find information on which areas of mathematics
are represented at which of the [more than 20 universities](https://www.4icu.org/kp/) in the
Democratic People's Republic of Korea (DPRK), and on which mathematicians
are working there?

The DPRK is a country with a population of about 25 million people,
and it is industrialised to a degree which has permitted it to successfully
construct nuclear weapons and ICBM's. So one would expect that there are
a decent number of mathematicians working at its universities.

However as the country operates an [intranet of its own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwangmyong_(network)), not much from there is visible from the open internet. -- So in particular Google will not help much further here.
Also, most results by researchers from the DPRK are published only in
national journals, and mathematicians from the country cannot be found
in the [Mathematics Genealogy Database](http://mathgenealogy.org/search.php). On the other hand, people in the DPRK who need the internet for their work
do have access, but with some sites blocked and email possibly monitored.

**Edit:** The possibly most interesting source available on the open internet I found so far is [NKScholar](http://www.nkscholar.com/). -- But firstly articles posted on that site are paywalled with prices in local currency, and secondly the site is Korean-language only -- so I can't tell how much one can really find there. Maybe someone else can tell more.

**Added on Jan 22, 2019:** As to the publications from the DPRK which have
appeared in international journals: there are so far 118 articles with at
least one author based in the DPRK which have reviews in MathSciNet.
Of these, 101 are from the year 2012 or later. The articles touch 34
two-digit MSC numbers, and have been written by more than 100 distinct
authors (where the exact number of the latter is not easy to determine due
to slightly varying romanizations of names etc.) based at about 20 distinct
institutions, mostly located in Pyongyang, the capital of the country.
Among these articles, 41 have been co-authored with colleagues from China,
9 have been co-authored with colleagues from Germany and 4 have been
co-authored with colleagues from other countries.
The areas represented best are MSC 35: *Partial differential equations*
and MSC 76: *Fluid mechanics* (together 47 papers)
-- but also e.g. MSC 11: *Number theory*, MSC 16: *Associative
rings and algebras*, MSC 26: *Real functions*, MSC 37: *Dynamical systems
and ergodic theory*, MSC 53: *Differential geometry*, MSC 54: *General
Topology* and MSC 55: *Algebraic topology* are represented with several
papers, each. Given that there are almost as many distinct authors as
there are papers, given the breadth of the areas covered and given that
it doesn't seem likely that the country's mathematicians have started to
work all of a sudden barely a decade ago, what is visible in MathSciNet
seems merely like the tip of an iceberg to me -- which emphasizes the
question about the "rest".

Comment: As far as I know there is some research in applied mathematics, but none in pure mathematics seems to be known. But this is only hearsay from professors in South Korea.

Comment: You say that you don't want politics in this, but then you throw wild claims (and lurid videos) into your OP... E.g. the US never declared war on Korea in the first place, so it can't be "formally still at war" with it. (the US acted under UNSCR 84, and military funding was given by Congress, but no formal declaration)

Comment: @ThiKu: Does the "this is only hearsay from professors in South Korea" apply to the first part of the first sentence of your comment as well, or can you say something more concrete with respect to applied mathematics?

Comment: Some funny mathematics problems (but irrelevant to the question): https://www.pri.org/stories/2013-04-24/can-you-solve-north-korean-math

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes -- that is what one gets among the first results when one googles for 'mathematics north korea' ... .

Comment: Maybe going via China, i.e. using Baidu instead of Google, gibes bigger chance of finding something online.

Comment: I know the problems of mathematical olympiads in North Korea (they are available in Internet), and they are quite nice.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Can you perhaps give the link (it doesn't seem to be easy to find with Google, and https://www.imomath.com/index.php?mod=23&options=other has only the problems from South Korea)?

Comment: @StefanKohl for example https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c217256_2013_north_korea_team_selection_test

Comment: I heard it mentioned that the Hungarian mathematician Gyula Katona (of Kruskal-Katona fame) was one of the very few mathematicians around with substantial academic contacts with both South and North Korea, perhaps he can advise.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://cryptome.org/dprk/dprk-papers.htm) are some articles on cryptography. (I do not claim the veracity of them, as there is a lot of misinformation.)

Comment: Yes, this set of eight papers posted in 2005 is one of the few poor sources one finds with Google.

Comment: I would bet that, going "deeper" in the web, one could find more.

Comment: Google chrome translates webpages without installing any plugin. It worked for me for your link. Looking at the titles one notes that there's a lot of applied math.

Comment: Yes, of course. -- This gives some headlines -- but no abstracts, author's affiliations or contact data, let alone full texts of articles.

Comment: Besides -- does the search function work for you in a useful way via the translator?

Comment: No, it does not work for me with the translator.

Comment: You can find in Math Reviews papers with authors affiliated with Kim Il-sung University, e.g. MR3225383, MR3232454 (in finite fields) MR3353738, MR3255419 (in differential geometry). Moreover, Math Reviews has institution information for Kim Il Sung University, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/institution.html?code=PRK-KISM .

Comment: Dear Stefan. Your e-mail is the one appearing in your webpage?

Comment: @EFinat-S Yes, it is.

Answer (score 8):

Doing a free search for "Pyongyang" on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/), seems to give papers from DPRK mathematicians. Around March of 2013, there appears to have been a spike in papers uploaded to the arXiv bearing the banner

> International Symposium in Commemoration of the 65th Anniversary of
>   the Foundation of **Kim Il Sung** University (Mathematics)
>   20－21. Sep. Juche100(2011)  Pyongyang DPR Korea

Here's an [example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4838). Doing some further digging reveals that the same authors have uploaded other preprints to the arXiv, but it's hard to search for them because of variations in how their names are latinized.

Comment: That search gives 12 results, as far as I see. -- And looking further from there, googling for "KISU-MATH-2011" yields several more papers.

Comment: The linked paper has a noteworthy introduction.

Comment: The great leader comrade Kim Il Sung said as follows.
“We should further strengthen scientific research and rapidly develop science and technology so that any scientific and technical problems in economic construction can be solved as soon as they arise and thus successfully make the national economy scientific and fully ensure that it becomes Juche-orientated and modern.”(“Kim Il Sung Works” Vol. 35, 312p)
This paper is concerned with the estimates of fundamental solution for higher order Schrödinger equation.

Comment: @ThiKu: Indeed! -- Though that type of introduction doesn't appear to be common even for papers from the DPRK. In fact this is the first time I see such text in a mathematical publication from there. -- Even more: a Google search for "We should further strengthen scientific research and rapidly develop" yields precisely this one result.

Comment: @StefanKohl Well now two, since this thread now shows up.

Answer (score 7):

Two mathematicians from North Korea I know are Kim, Jinhyon and Ju, Hyonhui. I like their paper:

- *Hausdorff dimension of the sets of Li-Yorke pairs for some chaotic dynamical systems including  A-coupled expanding systems*, Chaos Solitons Fractals **109** (2018) 246-251, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2018.02.021, https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4846, [Zbl 1390.37028](https://zbmath.org/1390.37028)

Comment: Interesting! -- By the way -- do you know which of the articles listed in zbMATH at https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai%3Akim.jinhyon are actually by Kim, Jinhyon (only the one you mentioned is published under the full name, and 35 others on the list are authored by some Kim, J.).

Comment: Sorry but I do not know this for sure.

Comment: Unrelatedly, there’s quite an interesting story about that journal and its former editor, Mohamed El Naschie. This is now nearly a decade ago and I don’t want to assume the new editors behave like the old ones. But interesting to say the least. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamed_El_Naschie

Comment: @pupshaw: That is indeed interesting. -- Do you think one can find a significant amount of serious research in that journal anyway?

Comment: @JörgNeunhäuserer: Since the paper you cite is far from my area of expertise, I cannot tell anything about its correctness or merits. -- Given what pupshaw said -- can you confirm it is a reasonable paper, or is it possible that it is not without reason that the authors have chosen a journal with that reputation?

Comment: About CS&F there is an analysis from 2010: https://www.richardpoynder.co.uk/Phoenix.pdf

Comment: @StefanKohl In my opinion it is a good paper! The authors generalize my results in Li-Yorke pairs of full Hausdorff dimension for some chaotic dynamical systems. (English) Zbl 1224.37011
Math. Bohem. 135, No. 3, 279-289 (2010).